# Regular expression to match 9 characters where first 2 are letters and then 6 numbers and then 1 letter

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have an asp textbox control, now using regular expression I want to validate that control, which should contain 9 characters where first 2 are letters and then 6 numbers and then 1 letter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i have a regular expression validator to validate the textbox, i need validation expression.

Comment: Surely, you have read the [documentation on .NET regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) before asking, right? (Aka [Do Your Homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).) ;-) Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I'm guessing, given his comment underneath my answer, he didn't add the `^` and `$` signs to match the start and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I know my Regex, you could use this: `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{6}[a-zA-Z]{1}$`.

(The `{1}` at the end isn't needed, but I though it looks good...)

How you check that is up to you. You can do this in code-behind (since you're using asp.net) or JS.

EDIT: Should also work with a `ValidationExpression`.

Here's a sample of this in use:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TB1" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TB1" ErrorMessage="2 letters, 6 digits and a letter, hotshot!" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{6}[a-zA-Z]{1}$" />
```

[image: Validator in action]

Comment: I set [\w]{2}[\d]{6}\w to validation expression, and it validates  aa2212314, where it should not. It does not validating last character

Comment: Try adding the initial ^ sign and & at the end. ;)

Comment: i used ^[\w]{2}[\d]{6}\w$ and still not validating last character

Comment: Try [a-zA-Z] instead of \w. My apologies: \w doesn't work like I thought it should.

Comment: Yeah thats what ive just found, ive changed all w to [a-zA-Z], and it works :):)

^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{6}[a-zA-Z]{1}$

Thanks Shaamaan for your help